# VLookup using Excel sheet to get data from another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have two Excel workbooks:
`one.xlsx`   `two.xlsx`

- `'[one.xlsx]Sheet1'!A:A` contains a list of 50 text strings.
- Each string is the name of one of 50 worksheets in `two.xlsx`
- where `_NAME_` is one of those 50 strings, I need a VLOOKUP formula in `'[one.xlsx]Sheet1'!B:B` to return a value from `'[two.xlsx]_NAME_'!A:A`

Comment: Please add a sample of your data and expected result.

Comment: Google for the 'INDIRECT()' function.